How can I be nice to people?
Can I know exactly how could I be a good muslim when communicating with people? I always get tired and/or unhappy deep down when communicating with people, even tho they were nice to me. I sometimes end up saying bad words to them. I really want to fix my relationship with my family and friends

You asked: "Can I know exactly how could I be a good muslim when communicating with people?" And I say, be honest: don't be rude, but don't crawl to their whims either.


According to a Hadeeth from Imam Ali PBUH:


مَن أَصلَحَ فِیما بَینَهُ وَ بَینَ اللّه، أَصلَحَ اللّه فِیما بَینَهُ
وَ بَینَ النّاس
Whoever corrects his relationship with God, God will correct his
relationship with people

You may ask how. Easy, whenever you see a person, remind that he/she is a creature of Allah, and behave how you know Allah wants you to behave to this creature of Him. Therefore only see Allah and not those individuals. You live in a world of only you and Allah. That would prevent you of any sin, eventhough if you think that sin will be helpful in some regards, or avoiding the sins will put you in some troubles. Be a good servant of Allah, and Allah will do what He knows to be the best for you.

According to another Hadeeth from Imam Ali PBUH:


يَا بُنَيَّ، اجْعَلْ نَفْسَكَ مِيزَاناً فِيمَا بَيْنَكَ وَ بَيْنَ
غَيْرِكَ، فَأَحْبِبْ لِغَيْرِكَ مَا تُحِبُّ لِنَفْسِكَ، وَ اكْرَهْ
لَهُ مَا تَكْرَهُ لَهَا
O dear child, put your ego as a measure between yourself and others,
then like for others what you like for yourself, and do not like for
others what you do not like for yourself

no need to explain ...

assalam alaikom there is this dua the the prophet pbh used to say
Ibn Mas’ud reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “O Allah, You have made my creation beautiful, thus make my character beautiful.”
Source: Ṣaḥīḥ Ibn Ḥibbān 959
Grade: Sahih li ghayrihi (authentic due to external evidence) according to Al-Arna’ut
